# when casting is need for clone() method?

Tags: java, clone

consider the code below:

```
ArrayList<Double> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
list1.add(1.5);
list1.add(2.5);
list1.add(3.5);
ArrayList<Double> list2 = (ArrayList<Double>)list1.clone();

Date[] list3 = {new Date(), new Date(4664316)};
Date[] list4 = list3.clone();

int[] list5 = {1, 2};
int[] list6 = list5.clone();
```

why list.clone() requires casting, while list3.clone() and list5.clone() don't need casting? I know the difference is between array and ArrayList, but not sure exactly why.

Answer (score 3):

Please read the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone%28%29).

> Note that all arrays are considered to implement the interface Cloneable and that the return type of the clone method of an array type T[] is T[] where T is any reference or primitive type.

But in ArrayList, an Object is returned, so a cast is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Clone() method signature returns an object type.

> By convention, the object returned by this method should be independent of this object (which is being cloned)

Hence the cast is required.

Arrays behave differently and return a correctly typed clone array. So no casting required.

Comment: then why list3 and 4 don't require casting?